# Creating a file system path branch in C#

Tags: c#, path

I have what I think is probably quite a simple question to answer (for someone).  Given a path, say C:\A\B\C\D\, what is the most efficient, compact and elegant way to re-create that path on the system, assuming it doesn't already exist (C:\A\B might, of course), in c#?

The only thing I can think of involves a rather grubby looking little path parser, with all of the potential pit-falls this entails.  I'm sure many people here will have encountered this little problem before and have a better solution than I can come up with.

So, your thoughts please gentlemen (and ladies)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\A\B\C\D\")` will do just fine.

Comment: Duh! I feel like such a twit.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: You're welcome :-) Obviously goes without saying that there's no error handling with this.

Comment: Sure.  It's got an exception handler around it.

Answer (score 2):

[MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.create%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
    // Specify the directories you want to manipulate.
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\MyDir");

    try 
    {
        // Determine whether the directory exists.
        if (di.Exists) 
        {
            // Indicate that it already exists.
            Console.WriteLine("That path exists already.");
            return;
        }

        // Try to create the directory.
        di.Create();
        Console.WriteLine("The directory was created successfully.");
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
    } 
    finally {}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\A\B\C\D\");
```

Creates all directories in the path if they don't already exist, and even returns you a DirectoryInfo object of the child directory (D, in this case).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look into [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx) and the ´Directory.exists´-Method.

This way you can detect if "C:\A\B\C\D..." already exists and if not you can create it with [Directory.Create(String directoryName)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx)...

Answer (score 1):

[Directory.CreateDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx) will take care of that for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
 string folderPath = "C:\A\B\C\D"
 if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(folderPath))
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
```